# How to get a specific section in a message exception in java?

Tags: java

I need to know how to get a specific section of an message generated by an exception in java, in debug mode, I have obtained the value I need, which attached image, but I need get that data in the code to generate a "Switch", I require something like this:

[image]

```
try 
{

processes .... 

} catch (SQLException ex) {

string reason = ex.**(how to get the failure reason)**; 

switch (reason) {

           case "_bt_check_unique": 

                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Error, the record already exists."); 

           break; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to call [`getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) on the exception object and then use the various getter methods on the [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) objects in the array that is returned.